# Change background color every 30s (fade transition)

Tags: css, colors, background, css-transitions, fade

I would like someone to tell me what's the code for making a webpage background color (the background color of the whole page) to change (fade transition) every 30s to a given color variety. Is it simple? I guess css will make it easier?

I've searched over the internet and I only found gradients which is not what I want. Thank you in advance. I 've search codepen and jsfiffle for examples but no one had something that simple :/

Example: While browsing my page I want the background color to change from blue to green and then to orange and again blue and so on so on... :)

Comment: define classes with a `background-color`, add a transition like `transition: background-color 1000ms linear;`, and use JavaScript to add/remove these classes.

Comment: Add did that but the how do I achieve the fade effect? Also can you be more specific about Javascript? Why to use js at all? Wouldn't be simpler if I call a class in my html page and leave it there as it is?

Comment: Yeah, you might be able to use css animations to do this

Comment: Thanks but I found my answer (below) . Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a jQuery approach, to complete Bogdan's answer, that takes 3 parameters: `selector` (example, ".container" or "div"), `colors` (an array of colors to switch in between) and `time` (controls how frequently the bgd color changes).
I set it for 3 seconds (`3000`) so you can see it in action easier, but you can increase it to 30000 (30 seconds).

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    function changeColor(selector, colors, time) {
        /* Params:
         * selector: string,
         * colors: array of color strings,
         * every: integer (in mili-seconds)
         */
        var curCol = 0,
            timer = setInterval(function () {
                if (curCol === colors.length) curCol = 0;
                $(selector).css("background-color", colors[curCol]);
                curCol++;
            }, time);
    }
    $(window).load(function () {
        changeColor(".container", ["green", "yellow", "blue", "red"], 3000);
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: red;
    height:500px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -khtml-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice!! Indeed :)  I hope this post will help other people that look for something similar :)

Answer (score 35):

It's also possible to do this without any JavaScript at all, using CSS3 animations.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  -webkit-animation: background 5s cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1) infinite;
  animation: background 5s cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1) infinite;  
}


@-webkit-keyframes background {
  0% { background-color: #f99; }
  33% { background-color: #9f9; }  
  67% { background-color: #99f; }
  100% { background-color: #f99; }
}

@keyframes background {
  0% { background-color: #f99; }
  33% { background-color: #9f9; }  
  67% { background-color: #99f; }
  100% { background-color: #f99; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I see that it runs pretty fast even though the time is set to 5s. Why's this happening? :)

Comment: It's the overall time of the animation, so it takes 5s divided by 3 so about 1.5s per color. The bezier function handles the fading, if you need more control over this, you can duplicate the background colors inside the keyframes (e.g. add 30% for #f99)

Answer (score 10):

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cq85k4a9/2/)

CSS:

```
body {
    background: blue; /* Initial background */
    transition: background .5s; /* .5s how long transitions shoould take */
}
```

Javascript:

```
var colors = ['green', 'orange', 'blue']; // Define Your colors here, can be html name of color, hex, rgb or anything what You can use in CSS
var active = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = colors[active];
    active++;
    if (active == colors.length) active = 0;
}, 30000);
```

Comment: well done my friend :) thank you very much for actually helping :)

Comment: Can I control how much time the color will stay on before it starts changing?

Comment: @Billef32 30000 controls interval between changes

Comment: 30000 is milliseconds? I mean can I put something like 15s as a value? or should I add transition-delay? I added a transition delay in css but it didn't work.

Comment: How can I change the code so that the counting starts with the colors in the array and does not have an initial color? Or in your example the first color to show would be green from the array and not blue. How can I do that please?